# Can you access a user's tag reputation/score via the API?

Tags: support, api, tags, reputation

Is it possible to retrieve a user's tag specific reputation/score via the API?  If not, is it possible to make an API call that returns enough information that you can calculate the value?

Comment: Any feedback out there?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no API route that gives you a user's tag specific reputation information.  The [/users/{ids}/tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-on-users#order=desc&sort=popular&ids=1288&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) route only returns the combined count of questions and answers that a user has posted in a tag, but not the reputation information that you can get on the [user profile tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard?tab=tags).  (Note: There's an app at [Badge Status for a particular Tag in Stackoverflow](https://stackapps.com/q/3527/9) that scrapes that page to get the information you're looking for.)