# Badge Status for a particular Tag in Stackoverflow

Tags: app

I was unsure if I could upload an Exe File so I created an Excel App instead of VB.net app.

**What is it regarding?**

I am sure you are aware but for people who are not, you can earn a Bronze, Silver, Gold in a particular tag depending on the votes that you have got + questions answered. To get the information manually, you can visit your profile and under `Tags`, calculate the number of votes + questions required for a particular badge. This process can be tedious if you are expecting the badges in several tags.

[image]

**What does it do?**

This application lets you do the following

1. Enter tags (max 5) and spits out an analysis for the Gold/Silver/Bronze stats for the relevant tag.
2. It also alerts you about the number of posts which have a high probability of getting Great Answer (Gold), Good Answer (Silver) and Nice Answer (bronze) for the relevant tag
3. For the curious, it also gives you a bifurcation of the Votes vs Questions in the relevant tag

**Snapshot**

[image]

**Note**

The VBA Project is not protected and you can use it freely. If you want you may enhance this App to your liking.

**File**

Please see below for updated version.

Suggestions to improve this are most welcome.

Comment: Looks great! I'll download this and see if I have any comments.

Comment: @JimmyPena: If you can wait till tomorrow, I am releasing an updated version which does a lot of new things :)

Comment: OK. What library are you using to parse the JSON response from the API? I assume that is what you are doing.

Comment: @JimmyPena: No, I am using the simple Webbrowser control in Excel and `getElementsByTagName` to scrape data. Before I post it here, if you want to test the new version, you can send me a blank email. It is almost ready

Comment: I can wait :) I'm going to play with the API myself.

Comment: You're the man, @Sid!

Comment: @Gaffi: Glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 4):

**Ver 1.1 released.**

New version lets you do the following

**1)** Verify your user ID so that there is no error.

[image]

**2)** A "Remember Me" checkbox for `User ID` so that you do not need to enter the ID again and again.

**3)** Automated the Tags textbox so you no longer need to type it out. The App will download the latest tags from your profile from which you can select.

[image]

**4)** A "Remember Me" checkbox for `Tags` as well so that you do not need to enter the tags again and again.

**5)** Option to export the Tags and Analysis to the worksheet so that you can do a manual comparison at a later date.

[image]

This is how the exported data looks like

[image]

**File**

The file can be downloaded from [here](http://sdrv.ms/MgX8aq).

**Direction on how to use it**

1. Enter User ID
2. Click on Verify
3. Click on Tags Button once app verifies you.
4. Select the relevant tags (max 5)
5. Click on Calculate button.

Suggestions to improve this are most welcome.